# Salesforce Topics lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, topics

I want to add to my lighting component a capability like Salesforce Topics.
Is there a lighting component ready for this?
Does Salesforce let you use the same component they are using on your custom pages?
If not any suggestion on some library/component I can use which gives the same functionality?

Comment: 'Like Salesforce Topics' ? you want to display topics in a custom page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to utilize the standard [Topic component](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_topics_records_admin_LEX.htm&type=5) on a custom lightning component, you **cannot** use it the way you want to.

For your questions:

> Is there a lighting component ready for this?

**No**. There is no lightning component available for this (yet). The one available is the standard component.

> Does Salesforce let you use the same component they are using on your custom pages?

**Yes**, if you are referring a lightning page with custom page. The standard components available can be used on pages built using lightning app builder or community builder depending on which component is available based on the page type.

But they are not available to be used on custom lightning components itself.

> If not any suggestion on some library/component I can use which gives the same functionality?

There's nothing readily available (as far as I can lookup), you will need to build one for your purposes. A starting point will be to enable *Topic* on the objects and utilize a custom component to add/view the topics associated to a particular record.